# Scrapy output not matching up with what I see when I click the link that Scrapy says it is crawling

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

this is my first question

I'm working on a Scrapy spider right now and it wasn't giving the output I expected. I am trying to get all the links from a page, but it is not getting any of them. Specifically, from [this page](https://www.amazon.com/s?rh=n%3A1055398%2Cn%3A%211063498%2Cn%3A1063278%2Cn%3A1063298%2Cn%3A684541011%2Cp_28%3Ashag&lo=image&pf_rd_i=684541011&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_p=00b00417-8753-4d7d-a195-6b32e72824d6&pf_rd_r=WNW5ETYC1B5T559W2E0Z&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-2&pf_rd_t=101&qid=1506387915&ref=s9_acss_bw_cg_ARfilers_4a1_w) I want all the product links.
To select them I am using

```
rug_urls = response.xpath('//a[@class="a-link-normal a-text-normal"]/@href').getall()
```

but this gives me nothing. So just to see what would come out, I used

```
rug_urls = response.xpath('//a').getall()
```

and it gives me

```
[u'<a onclick="window.location.reload()">Try different image</a>', 
u'<a href="https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/ref=footer_cou?ie=UTF8&amp;nodeId=508088">Conditions of Use</a>', 
u'<a href="https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/ref=footer_privacy?ie=UTF8&amp;nodeId=468496">Privacy Policy</a>']
```

which doesn't seem to match up with the site at all. Yet the console output certainly tells me this is the link that is being crawled. I am especially confused because earlier my code worked as intended, but only one single time, and it hasn't changed in any meaningful way from then. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you test this in `scrapy shell`? Because your first XPath works perfectly for me. It might be the case that Amazon detected what you are doing and they are blocking you.

Comment: How could I know whether that was the case?

Comment: Open the URL in `scrapy shell` then run `view(response)` to see the response in the browser. Maybe there's a message.

Comment: On the other hand, maybe one of the small changed you made actually has this effect. Would you be able to post more code from your spider?

Comment: For some reason when I enter `scrapy shell` followed by the url, the `>>>` never comes up, and when I enter `view(response)` on the blank line, the shell crashes.

Comment: Did you wrap the URL in  quotes? It contains a `&` character, which requires you to quote the whole URL.

Comment: Amazon is not easy to scrape, they might be blocking you, you can print entire page's source-code like `self.logger.info(response.body)` to see if you are getting correct page, or you can use `open_in_browser(response)` to see what page it got scraped.

Comment: Hi. Sorry I wasn't wrapping it in quotes, so that was my problem. `view(response)` gives me the desired page. However when I use `self.logger.info(response.body)` there is a line that says "Sorry we just need to make sure you're not a robot." Is there any way around this, or is my project doomed?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for the help everyone.

The output was not what was expected based on what I saw when I clicked the link provided by the console output because the spider was getting the *prove you're not a robot* page from amazon as its response.

I discovered this by using `self.logger.info(response.body)` to see the response my spider was receiving